# Определение раскладки текста

Tags: java

Как с помощью java определить является ли этот текст английский (состоит из английского набора символов) или русский и функции с работой символа, например перевод символа из русского в английский. Не пишите велосипедов, меня интересуют готовые api и ссылки на скачивание.

Пример:

"АБВГД" - Выдать информацию о том что строка состоит из русских символов

"AERGO" - Выдать информацию о том что строка состоит из английских символов

"АБВГДG" - Выдать информацию о том что строка состоит из русских и английских символов

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Приведите пример входных и выходных параметров такой программы.

Comment: я думаю, автор хочет [Punto Switcher](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_Switcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встречайте - велосипед. Если есть пунктуация, то можно его выбросить с помощью тех же регулярных выражений. Для лучшего понимая не стал оптимизировать. Так что, это можно написать компактнее.

```
String testArr[] = {"ABCD", "АВБГ", "ABВГ"};
Pattern cyrillic = Pattern.compile("^[а-яА-Я]+$");
Pattern latin = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
Matcher mCyrillic;
Matcher mLatin;
for (String test : testArr) {
    mCyrillic = cyrillic.matcher(test);
    mLatin = latin.matcher(test);
    if (mCyrillic.find() && !mLatin.find()){
        System.out.println(test + " is cyrillic");
    }
    else if (!mCyrillic.find() && mLatin.find()){
        System.out.println(test + " is latin");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(test + " is mixed");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABCD is latin
АВБГ is cyrillic
ABВГ is mixed
```

Готовых таких решений не знаю (и зачем?)

Comment: А хотя можно и регулярные выражения)))

Comment: Только не хватает написать регулярку по замене символов, например все английские заменить на все русские

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, вы про транслит? Если да, то нужно сделать что-то типа карты для замены символов. Типа "Символ - Замена". И по ней уже посимвольно заменять.